# Bootstrap modal dialog not showing when using fade animation

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4, bootstrap-modal

I use Bootstrap’s JavaScript modal plugin to add dialogs to my application, I successfully use it, but I'm facing an issue when I try to use fade animation when a modal dialog is opened or closed.

Following the instruction in [Bootstrap documentation](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.2/components/modal/) and [w3schools](https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_modal.asp), If I used the following tag:

```
<div id="myModal" class="modal" role="dialog">
```

The popup modal open successfully without any fade animation

[image]

When I want to used fade animation I added `fade` to the modal class:

```
<div id="myModal" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
```

The result was transparent background without showing popup modal !

[image]

I used `Bootstrap v4.3.1` ... What I miss here !!!

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I think if you just add the `fade` class from javascript it will not work. You need to add `show` class too. But if you call it via bootstrap way, i think its ok

Comment: @Faytraneozter, Thanks for your comment, But regarding to the links that I mentioned in my question, just adding fade and there's no show in there

Comment: Just see the 'myModal' div in inspect. and increase the z-index of #myModal and check.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Bootstrap 4 modal box works perfectly fine with fade class. Please refer to [W3schools](https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap4/tryit.asp?filename=trybs_modal_nofade&stacked=h)

Below is the example for the same if you were looking out for fade animation of modal in bootstrap 4

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>

  <div class="container">
    <!-- Button to Open the Modal -->
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">
    Open modal
  </button>

    <!-- The Modal -->
    <div class="modal fade" id="myModal">
      <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">

          <!-- Modal Header -->
          <div class="modal-header">
            <h4 class="modal-title">Modal Heading</h4>
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
          </div>

          <!-- Modal body -->
          <div class="modal-body">
            Modal body..
          </div>

          <!-- Modal footer -->
          <div class="modal-footer">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
          </div>

        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>

</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem when i was triying to open modal without button. I don't know why but instad of this:

```
$('#myModal').show();
```

doing this worked:

```
$('#myModal').modal("show");
```

Answer (score 1):

Replace tags such as "data-bs-target" tags with simply "data-target", removing the "-bs-" makes it work.

Answer (score 0):

see following code:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
 <!-- <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">-->
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-GJzZqFGwb1QTTN6wy59ffF1BuGJpLSa9DkKMp0DgiMDm4iYMj70gZWKYbI706tWS" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <!-- <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.0/jquery.min.js"></script> -->
 <!--  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script> -->
 <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.6/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-wHAiFfRlMFy6i5SRaxvfOCifBUQy1xHdJ/yoi7FRNXMRBu5WHdZYu1hA6ZOblgut" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-B0UglyR+jN6CkvvICOB2joaf5I4l3gm9GU6Hc1og6Ls7i6U/mkkaduKaBhlAXv9k" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</head>
<body>

<div class="container">
  <h2>Modal Example</h2>
  <!-- Trigger the modal with a button -->
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">Open Modal</button>

  <!-- Modal -->
  <div class="modal fade" id="myModal" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
    
      <!-- Modal content-->
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
          <h4 class="modal-title">Modal Header</h4>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
          <p>Some text in the modal.</p>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        </div>
      </div>
      
    </div>https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56521289/bootstrap-modal-dialog-not-showing-when-using-fade-animation#
  </div>
  
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

The modal is actually working but with full transparancy.

This might be the result of updating JQuery and/or bootstrap and NOT updating the css's involved.

Check out the css settings for '.fade'.

Remark: JQuery and bootstrap have to be in sync for modals.